# Can you create a "by-value" array in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm working on translating some code from Fortran to C#. In Fortran, arrays inside structures with fixed length are contiguous regions of memory, like in C. For example

```
program main
  type my_type
    integer :: xs(3)
  end type

  type(my_type) :: foo, bar

  foo = my_type(xs = [1, 2, 3])
  bar = foo
  foo%xs(1) = 0
  print *, foo ! prints "0 2 3"
  print *, bar ! prints "1 2 3"
end program
```

The codebase I'm translating makes use of this, a *lot*. I'd to mimic this in C#, if possible. I know if I define a `struct`, then the expression `x = y` would copy all values from `y` to `x`, but arrays are still references.

Is there a way in C# to make a value type with arrays of fixed size that are "by value" inside the struct?

I'd like to avoid implementing `Clone()` and recursively calling it because it's (1) easy to forget and (2) is likely slower than copying one big chunk of memory.

I'm also aware of the `[StructLayout]` attribute, but it only affects marshaling.

Edit:
I also need to handle arrays of other non-primitive value types.

Comment: Arrays in C# are guaranteed to be contiguous regions of memory, as well. Having an array be allocated from the heap, passed by reference, and eventually garbage collected does NOT stop the object from being contiguous within itself. It's even possible to do pointer arithmetic to access index locations.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I think the OP means that the first byte of the array *contents* contiguously follows the last byte of the preceding item in the array (ignoring packing) so in theory you could blit the entire struct memory to create a copy.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, that happens with C# arrays. The difference in C# is how they are passed to a method or assigned to another variable, but an array in C# is still guaranteed to be one block of contiguous memory (again: you can even do pointer arithmetic to find the value at a specific index). That's why we have Lists and arrays as separate things. Now, with an array as a member of a struct, the struct still only stores the reference. I do get that. But the array itself is contiguous.

Comment: I mean when it's part of an array - obviously given `struct Test { public int[] Array; }` then `Marshal.SizeOf<Test>()` will return the size of a pointer regardless of the size of the data referenced by `Array`. I think the OP wants the size to include the data of the array (without any ref), i.e. it's contiguous with the rest of the non-ref struct elements. (Which I think is what the inline arrays of C# 12 will do)

Comment: @MatthewWatson _"Not yet, but it's coming in C#12"_ - was not C# 12 released with .NET 8? AFAIK compiler already [extensively uses the feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78113476/2501279).

Comment: In addition to the [inline arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/inline-arrays) feature you can try looking into [fixed size buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code?redirectedfrom=MSDN#fixed-size-buffers) which can be what you need.

Comment: @GuruStron Aha yes, brain fade / looking at outdated web page. Yes, it's available now.

Comment: If I understand the example, a common c# solution would be a struct with separate fields, like a `vector3int` with `int x, y, z` fields/properties. You could then provide an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) if you want to access it like `myVector[1]`, and/or implement `IEnumerable<T>`. But the best solution will likely depend on what your type represent, and what they are used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [inline arrays/fixed-sized buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/inline-arrays) which were introduced with C# 12.

For example (this does not require `unsafe` code):

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Demo demo1 = new Demo {
            SomeDouble = 42.42,
            SomeInteger = 42
        };

        demo1.ThreeInts[0] = 100;
        demo1.ThreeInts[1] = 200;
        demo1.ThreeInts[2] = 300;

        Demo demo2 = demo1;

        Console.WriteLine(demo2.ThreeInts[0]); // Prints 100
        Console.WriteLine(demo2.ThreeInts[1]); // Prints 200
        Console.WriteLine(demo2.ThreeInts[2]); // Prints 300
    }
}

[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(3)]
public struct ThreeIntArray
{
    private int _firstElement;
}

public struct Demo
{
    public int SomeInteger;
    public ThreeIntArray ThreeInts;
    public double SomeDouble;
}
```

You can also verify that the data is contiguous within the array (this requires `unsafe` code):

```
unsafe
{
    var p1 = &demo1.SomeInteger;
    var p2 = &demo1.ThreeInts;
    var p3 = &demo1.ThreeInts[0];
    var p4 = &demo1.SomeDouble;

    Console.WriteLine((nint)p1);
    Console.WriteLine((nint)p2);
    Console.WriteLine((nint)p3);
    Console.WriteLine((nint)p4);
}
```

The output of this will vary depending on where things are in memory, but the following will always be true:

```
p2 == p1 + sizeof(int)
p3 == p2
p4 == p2 + 3 * sizeof(int)
```

For example, when I ran it the following was output:

```
935060826680 p1
935060826684 p2
935060826684 p3 
935060826696 p4
```

(Note that it's not actually guaranteed that the elements of a struct will be contiguous until marshalled, but it *is* guaranteed that the elements of an inline array are contiguous.)

Comment: Great! Looks like it also works with a generic type argument, just not a generic size. This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement what you need is with a fixed size buffer, which has `struct` copy semantics. The downside of course is that it's a fixed size buffer, ie you need to know the exact size of it at creation time, but in your case you look like you do know it.

Also, because C# doesn't support value type generic arguments, the array count has to be a constant as well. The workaround for that is source generation, you can easily set up one to generate the types you need as you need them.

With those caveats out of the way, here's [a quick example that works](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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):

The fixed size array with regular C# semantics (strongly typed `IEnumerable<>` and indexed setter and getter):

```
unsafe struct FixedIntArray3: IEnumerable<int>
{
    public fixed int Buffer[3];
    
    public int this[int idx]
    {
        get => Buffer[idx];
        set => Buffer[idx] = value;
    }
    
    public FixedIntArray3(IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        int idx = 0;
        foreach(var item in source)
            Buffer[idx++] = item; 
    }
    
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            yield return this[i];
    }
    
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

And a quick demo:

```
        FixedIntArray3 arr = new([3, 2, 1]);
        foreach(var item in arr)
            Console.WriteLine(item);         // 3, 2, 1
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        var arr2 = arr;
        arr[0] = 4;
        
        foreach(var item in arr)
            Console.WriteLine(item);        // 4, 2, 1
        foreach(var item in arr2)
            Console.WriteLine(item);        // 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: This is great, but I neglected to mention in my question that it needs to work for arrays of other non-primitive value types. C# doesn't like `public fixed SomeStruct Buffer[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

One option to look is to use the [fixed sized buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code?redirectedfrom=MSDN#fixed-size-buffers):

```
unsafe
{   
    var x = new Buffer();
    x.fixedBuffer[0] = 42;
    var y = x;
    x.fixedBuffer[0] = 777;
    Console.WriteLine(x.fixedBuffer[0]); // 777
    Console.WriteLine(y.fixedBuffer[0]); // 42 
}

internal unsafe struct Buffer
{
    public fixed int fixedBuffer[2];
}
```

Demo [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUNAZwEMAzAUzwG88ACOm1TATgAoCBLALzIHsSWAQhBLkwASjEBuerXoA3ImBoAPGgF4aUMgHcaQkWTAspsusoB0JdsrJx9ogNoAGALrqaAFnSTTNBUoBPd2UfXHoVS2tbe0NnNw0AdiTQ8MZWCysbO2FHVxMw+jSWAMismLA4/IBfPDx2KGBDKCIAGxpCUjIaAmBIAGNgPRzDKl9UAGYaTNsaesHp7IMK9BdQqqA). Though this requires `unsafe` context for working "directly" with it.

The same should be achievable with the [inline arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/inline-arrays) available since C# 12:

```
var x = new Buffer();
x[0] = 42;
var y = x;
x[0] = 777;
Console.WriteLine(x[0]); // 777
Console.WriteLine(y[0]); // 42


[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(2)]
public struct Buffer
{
    private int _firstElement;
}
```

Demo [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUAAnz0MIDcBDMfAD3wF58oBTAd3wCEIAzLpsACgCUAbmIlqAbQAMAXXr4ALOlEESFKgE951FSRrS5DAOwndJVJgCc/SbJFjCF6xoP3cePBIsA6AErRgAEsAWyZvAGEAe2CAB0CAGz4AZT5SQIBjJgBnbwBJKHjA5gBBMDByDX50QRk8VABmfCzgSHTgDm5eMDwAbwd8GLBAimAmfCL2gH0uQLBmgFFE0KhgFQBfIA===).

Answer (score 0):

## Implementation

A way of copying the contents of the array is to create an immutable array and copy the contents of the array. Another way is to use `Array.Copy()`. Another way is to create a contiguous memory block at a certain location and move the contents of the array at once at the newly created contiguous memory block.

```
        public static Data[] DeepCopy<Data>(Data[]data)
        {
            // CREATE AN IMUTABLE ARRAY AND COPY THE DATA OF THE ORIGINAL ARRAY
            ImmutableArray<Data> copy = data.ToImmutableArray<Data>();

            // PARSE THE IMUTABLE ARRAY TO A NORMAL ARRAY AND RETURN
            return copy.ToArray<Data>();
        }


        public static Data[] CopyMemoryChunk<Data>(Data[] data)
        {
            // CREATE A CONTIGUOUS MEMORY BLOCK AND ALLOCATE THE VALUS OF THE ARRAY
            // AT THE MEMORY ADDRESS WHERE THE CONTIGUOUS MEMORY BLOCK IS CREATED
            Memory<Data> data_obj = new Memory<Data>(data);

            // PARSE THE CONTENTS OF THE CONTIGUOUS MEMORY BLOCK TO AN ARRAY AND RETURN
            return data_obj.ToArray();
        }
```

## RESULT

- At small sets (sub 1000 integers), is faster to copy the address using `CopyTo()` or to make a deep copy if the original array using an immutable array, than creating a contiguous memory block and storing the values at the contiguous memory block's address.

[image]

- At bigger sets (10000 and over), copying the values using `CopyTo()` or using an immutable array to create a deep copy, is slower than creating a contiguous memory block and storing the values at the contiguous memory block's address

[image]

## CODE

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace DeepCopy
{
    class Program
    {

        public static Data[] DeepCopy<Data>(Data[]data)
        {
            // CREATE AN IMUTABLE ARRAY AND COPY THE DATA OF THE ORIGINAL ARRAY
            ImmutableArray<Data> copy = data.ToImmutableArray<Data>();

            // PARSE THE IMUTABLE ARRAY TO A NORMAL ARRAY AND RETURN
            return copy.ToArray<Data>();
        }


        public static Data[] CopyMemoryChunk<Data>(Data[] data)
        {
            // CREATE A CONTIGUOUS MEMORY BLOCK AND ALLOCATE THE VALUS OF THE ARRAY
            // AT THE MEMORY ADDRESS WHERE THE CONTIGUOUS MEMORY BLOCK IS CREATED
            Memory<Data> data_obj = new Memory<Data>(data);

            // PARSE THE CONTENTS OF THE CONTIGUOUS MEMORY BLOCK TO AN ARRAY AND RETURN
            return data_obj.ToArray();
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
            int number_of_tests = 100000;
            int number_of_elements = 100;
            
            CopyUsingDeepCopy(true, number_of_elements);
            CopyUsingContinguousMemoryBlock(true, number_of_elements);
            TestSpeed(number_of_tests, number_of_elements);
        }   

        public static void TestSpeed(int number_of_tests, int number_of_elements)
        {
            long TotalCopyUsingDeepCopyTime = 0;
            long TotalCopyUsingContinguousMemoryBlockTime = 0;
            long TotalArrayCopyTime = 0;

            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

            for(int i = 0; i < number_of_tests; i++)
            {
                s.Start();
                CopyUsingDeepCopy(false, number_of_elements);
                s.Stop();
                TotalCopyUsingDeepCopyTime += s.ElapsedTicks;
                s.Reset();
                
                s.Start();
                CopyUsingContinguousMemoryBlock(false, number_of_elements);
                s.Stop();
                TotalCopyUsingContinguousMemoryBlockTime += s.ElapsedTicks;
                s.Reset();

                s.Start();
                int [] deep_copy = new int[number_of_elements];
                int[] values = new int[number_of_elements];
                for(int count = 0; count < number_of_elements; count++)
                {
                    values[count] = count;
                }
                values.CopyTo(deep_copy, 0);
                s.Stop();
                TotalArrayCopyTime += s.ElapsedTicks;
                s.Reset();
            }

            
            Console.WriteLine("Average timer ticks took for deep copy: " + (double)(TotalCopyUsingDeepCopyTime / number_of_tests));
            Console.WriteLine("Average timer ticks took for contigugous memory block: " + (double)(TotalCopyUsingContinguousMemoryBlockTime / number_of_tests));
            Console.WriteLine("Average timer ticks took for 'ArrayCopy()': " + (double)(TotalArrayCopyTime / number_of_tests));
        }


        public static void CopyUsingDeepCopy(bool print, int number_of_elements)
        {
            if(print == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nCopying using deep copy:\n");
            }

            int[] values = new int[number_of_elements];
            for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++)
            {
                values[i] = i;
            }

            int[]copy = DeepCopy<int>(values);
            values[0] = 123456; 

            if(print == true)
            {
                PrintValues(values, copy);
            }

        }

        public static void CopyUsingContinguousMemoryBlock(bool print, int number_of_elements) 
        {
            if(print == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nCopying using continguous memory block:\n");
            }

            int[] values = new int[number_of_elements];
            for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++)
            {
                values[i] = i;
            }

            int[]copy = CopyMemoryChunk<int>(values);
            values[0] = 123456;

            if(print == true)
            {
                PrintValues(values, copy);
            }
        }


        public static void PrintValues(int[]arr_1, int[]arr_2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Values in original object:\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < arr_1.Length; i++)
            {
                if(i != arr_1.Length - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(arr_1[i] + ", ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(arr_1[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Values in copy object:\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < arr_2.Length; i++)
            {
                if(i != arr_2.Length - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(arr_2[i] + ", ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(arr_2[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

## SPECS

The program was ran using the following specs:
[image: specs]