# Does fixed buffer give any benefits when using for reading serial port?

Tags: c#, serial-port

Let's say we will recieve next package:
2 byte `address`,
byte `obs0`,
byte `obs1`, ..., byte `obs8`.

I want to accumulate some number of packages in `Queue<T>` and the serialize them. I can represent package like this:

```
struct Record {
    short addr;
    byte[] obss = new byte[9];
}
```

Or I could you the same struct, but use fixed buffer:

```
unsafe fixed byte obss[9];
```

If I got it right `fixed` keyword prevents from moving data inside of memory, which it the thing garbage collector sometimes does and that affects performance. So if I won't modificate `obs` after getting package, but only read once dequeuing when serializing object, does it make sense to use `fixed`?

I think it's a little bit overcomplicated for this example, but I want to know how it works for general case (or are there any corner cases when such thing will be useful).

Comment: This is not the correct use of `fixed`. Even if it stops that particular array from being moved, it will not prevent a GC from running. If you have a critical section of code during which writes to a hardware device must not be interrupted, you are using the wrong operating system - but you may be able to mitigate by using [`TryStartNoGCRegion`](https://mattwarren.org/2016/08/16/Preventing-dotNET-Garbage-Collections-with-the-TryStartNoGCRegion-API/). But are you *actually* having any issues with your current code?

Comment: What speeds are we talking about? Is there a performance issue that needs to be solved? With every optimization you have to ask yourself: do I need this? optimization can give less flexibility, or more overhead in other places. Don't preemptively optimize/over-optimize. (and if' you're using C# at all, you shouldn't generally be worried with these micro-optimizations anyhow IMHO.)

Comment: Also to clarify: A fixed-size buffer in a struct (which contains no ref types) does NOT prevent that struct from being moved in memory by the GC unless the struct is on the stack. In this context, the `fixed` keyword is being used to store the array data within the struct itself rather than via a reference array.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, @jhbonarius, thanks for your comments. As I've said, my suggestion of using ``fixed`` is overcomplecated for this example and, yes, even if it worked the way I think it would it will be over-optimisation that is not good. 
To clarify: my question splits into two parts: does it work that way (and as I've got it doesn't) and is there hypothetical situation when such optimisation make sense.

Comment: My advice (much shorter version of my answer): just use two fields - a `long` and a `byte`  - to represent the 9 bytes of payload data inside `Record`; it'll stop you going insane (take it from one who already took *way* too many steps in that direction) - but note my comments on the *order* of those fields (in my longer answer)

Comment: @MarcGravell, yes, I know that trick (unfortunately I have wome experience with MCU), but still you answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I got it right fixed keyword prevents from moving data inside of memory, which it the thing garbage collector sometimes does and that affects performance.

No; there are *two* meanings of `fixed` in C#, and *in this context*, it means "fixed (size) buffer", i.e. a chunk of raw memory in a type that is *not* a reference to an array, but is *directly in the containing type*. A fixed (size) buffer doesn't mean the data can't move - it moves with the containing type, which could *itself* be on the heap; because of this, whenever accessing a fixed (size) buffer directly, you must use the *other* meaning of `fixed` (stack-bound pinning) to access the unmanaged interior pointer without risk of it moving from underneath you.

Fixed (size) buffers *are* useful for representing a chunk of bytes without needing an array, so if *that* is what you want: *great*; yes, it'll do that, but they're a bit of a pain to work with. You *might* find it easier to use manual bit packing, i.e. use a `ulong` and a `byte`, and use shift operations to get the individual components; i.e.

```
short addr;
byte last;
long first8;
```

Note I put `last` after `addr` to help with "packing" - in that order it packs to 16 bytes, where-as if we order `last` *after* `first8`, it packs to 24 bytes (unless we use explicit field layout).

Fixed (size) buffers have a few uses, but if the API you're using it with takes *arrays*: it won't help you at all *because they're not arrays*. If the API you're using it with takes *unmanaged pointers*, you'll need to maintain `fixed` around that usage. If the API you're using it with takes spans or *managed* pointers, you can use `fixed` over the *unmanaged* pointer and then coerce that to a *managed* pointer (and a span, on modern .NET but not on .NET Framework) inside the `fixed` region (this step can be shortcut a bit in .NET 8 via "inline arrays", which manifest as spans). And if you don't know what *all of these terms mean*: this isn't the API for you :)

Comment: Yeap, at first I was thinking about representing chunk of bytes, but then I wanted to know if there were any performance implications of such one.

Comment: You could also use an inline array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78147804/can-you-create-a-by-value-array-in-c/78148049#78148049

Comment: @dragondangun performance is complex and cannot be opined without a specific scenario in mind; what is the performance critical scenario? if you don't know that yet: *stop optimizing* ;p

Comment: @MatthewWatson see 'this step can be shortcut a bit in .NET 8 via "inline arrays", which manifest as spans'

Comment: It's more than just a shortcut - it also prevents the need for `unsafe` code, which is quite a big difference.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I must start optimizing if I want to stop doing it :-) I understand that before optimizing something you need to understand what you want to achieve and that each case must be considered separatly, but sometimes we can say that some practice have such cons and such prons, e.g. try to use more spatial and temporal locality while working with matrices. If we do that we'll get the way better performance, but code readability will be awful.

Comment: @dragondangun indeed; and I'm saying that *until we have more context* "just use 3 fields" is a good first step; if we want an array-like access to `obs`, then I might be tempted to create my own span over raw memory - see https://gist.github.com/mgravell/d45b6d813dfca9aa0d8d057b03851a0e (this means that we get nice bounds checking etc automatically)